# nested if in algorithm2e giving errors

Tags: pdftex, algorithm2e

Here is the code, I have tried:

```
 \documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
 \usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,algoruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm}[H]
 \For {i in range(10)} {


  \If{i==2}
  {
  print value of i=2;
  \If{i==4} /* giving error*/
  { 
  print value of i=4;
  }
 } 
 \uIf {flag==1} { print 1;
 }


 \uIf {flag==2} { print 2;   
 }
 \uIf {flag==3} { print 3;   /* giving error*/
 }
 \Else { do something else;
 }
 }
 \end{algorithm}
 \end{document}
```

How to resolve nested if and else if errors?

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Pplease extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` For start also remove all empty lines in your code.

Answer (score 2):

With `algorithm2e` lines must be ended by `\;` (with the preceding `\`), or, if you want a comment, lines must be ended with one of the line-ending comment macros `\tcc*[r]`, `\tcc*[l]` (C style `/* */` right and left aligned) or `\tcp*[r]` and `\tcp*[l]` (C++ style `//` right or left aligned). From the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) on page 4:

> Very Important:  each line MUST end with \; only those with a macro
>   beginning a block should not end with \;.

See also section 10.3 on page 32 for the comment syntax.

Note that at the end of a block it is not really necessary to end a line with `\;` because the block also ends the line (see the example below in the second nested if statement). However, if you always end the line with this you can't forget it in other cases where it is essential.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,algoruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetNoFillComment
\For {i in range(10)} {
\If{i==2}
{
    print value of i=2\;
    \If{i==4}{ 
        print value of i=4\tcc*[l]{giving error}
        \If{i=$\sqrt{-1}$}{
            print I'm aginary!
        }
    }
} 
\uIf {flag==1} { print 1\;
}


\uIf {flag==2} { print 2\;   
}
\uIf {flag==3} { print 3\tcc*[l]{giving error}
}
\Else { do something else\;
}
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Note the command `\SetNoFillComment` at the start of the algorithm, this prevents the closing `*/` to stretch to the right margin. You can also set this globally using the `nofillcomment` package option.

Result:

[image]

Comment: OP example will work fine if (s)he will move `/* giving error*/` from 4th line on the end of the 5th line. Nice answer (+1)!

Comment: Thanks for such a great explanation